# Faster way to go from directory bookmark to file heading?

Tags: dired, find-file, bookmarks

I currently have a dired bookmark set to a directory. So in order to access a particular heading, the sequence is as follows:

1. Bookmarks keybind, type initial letters of directory bookmark.
2. (Dired fullscreen buffer is open) Use dired file goto, type beginning of filename, press enter twice
3. Use org-goto within the org buffer.

I'd like instead to be able to go from a keybinding to a find buffer that allows me to type the bookmark for the directory, then the file, then the heading, all of that without changing buffers and with tab completion. For example, after pressing a keybinding for this, I'd write What I'm trying to do is access a file heading by writing something like: `<bookmark>/<directory1>/<directory2>/<file>/<heading>`, and be at the heading I wanted. Are there ready-made packages or configs that could allow me to do that?

Comment: Are you expecting to type the full (bookmark, filename, heading) without any completion help? If so, that would be easily doable (I think - I haven't tried it), but typing complete names in all cases seems harder to me than using completion at each step.

Comment: @NickD my whole issue is that I'd like to be able to use completion! mixing bookmarks with filepaths with headings

Comment: That is hard(er) - I think (again I have not tried anything).

Comment: Is this about Org mode's "bookmarks" or about ordinary Emacs bookmarks? I don't really follow what you're asking, FWIW. What are you trying to do: open a Dired buffer by jumping to a bookmark? Open a file (you tagged this `find-file`)? Please specify the step-by-step recipe you're looking for.

Comment: @Drew The dired directory is reached with Emacs bookmarks. What I'm trying to do is access a file heading by writing something like: `<bookmark>/<directory1>/<directory2>/<file>/<heading>`, in such a way that tab completion is available. I've tagged this `find-file` in case there was a way of configuring `C-x C-f` to do what I wanted. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not clear to me. Why don't you just bookmark that heading? Or bookmark that file (and then use Imenu or search to go to the heading)? What's really not clear is why you want to go to a Dired buffer but then choose the file and heading using completion. Why use a bookmark at all, if you want to actually specify `<directory1>/<directory2>/<file>/<heading>` (maybe with completion)? Sounds a bit like an [X-Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), to me.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the answer! I don't bookmark the heading because I would like to be able to access over 1000 (and growing, with my org notes) headings in this manner. I don't necessarily want to go the a Dired buffer, it's just the only way I've found to bookmark a directory. I use a bookmark to specify part of the path, instead of having to specify the entirety of the path, i.e., it is faster to use the procedure mentioned in my main post, than to write the path with `C-x C-f`, because the latter has no ability to deal with bookmarks.

Comment: Have you tried `consult-org-agenda`. I have bound it to `C-x o` globally and access all my org headings with that (all files are added to Agenda with `org-agenda-file-to-front`

Comment: Put all such info in the question, to clarify it. Essentially, you want a shortcut way to use `C-x C-f` with a predefined directory. And you might have several such predefined directories - and that's what made you think of Dired bookmarks.

Comment: How many very-different predefined directories do you really need, for this? Why not just define a separate command for each, binding `default-directory` to the appropriate directory around an interactive call to `find-file`? Or have a command that lets you choose (completion) which predefined directory to use?

Comment: @Drew thanks for the `default-directory` mention! ended up using that to create my own custom command and predefining the directories I want in my script. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe post your solution as an answer, in that case. Answered questions help others. (You can accept your own answer.)

Comment: @Drew will do, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly edited ChatGPT-generated script that at least allowed me to use custom "bookmarks" with `find-file`, using Drew's suggestion. If anyone has ideas of how to extend navigation up to org file headings, please let me know!

```
(require 'vertico)

(defvar my-choices-alist
  '(("Choice1" . "/path/to/directory1")
    ("Choice2" . "/path/to/directory2")
    ("Choice3" . "/path/to/directory3")
    ("Choice4" . "/path/to/directory4")
    ("Choice5" . "/path/to/directory5")
    ("Choice6" . "/path/to/directory6")
    ("Choice7" . "/path/to/directory7")
    ("Choice8" . "/path/to/directory8")
    ("Choice9" . "/path/to/directory9")
    ("Choice10" . "/path/to/directory10")))

(defun my-find-file-command ()
  "Prompt for input using vertico, open a file, and set `default-directory` to the previous buffer's directory."
  (interactive)
  (let ((choices (mapcar #'car my-choices-alist))
        (selected-choice nil)
        (previous-dir default-directory))

    (setq selected-choice (completing-read "Select a choice: " choices))

    (if (assoc selected-choice my-choices-alist)
        (let* ((directory (cdr (assoc selected-choice my-choices-alist)))
               (file-to-open (read-file-name "Open file: " directory)))
          (find-file file-to-open)
          (setq default-directory previous-dir)
          (message "Opened file and set default directory to the previous buffer's directory: %s" default-directory))
      (message "Invalid choice: %s" selected-choice))))
```